# Nim: let statement without assignment

Tags: nim-lang

I want to have a single assignment variable but make the assignment later (in a different block).

For example:

```
let n: int
try:
  n = parseInt paramStr(1)
except ValueError:
  quit "Expected Number
```

Is this impossible right now? If so, why?
Also what is the best alternative in this situation?

I considered this:

```
let n =
  try:
    parseInt paramStr(2)
  except ValueError:
    -1
if n == -1:
  quit "Expected a number"
```

but doesn't look nice of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [impossible given the current implementation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#the-let-statement), your alternative seems reasonable to me (or use a var with initial value of `-1`). Otherwise you can use the `parseopt` module to abstract the command line input verification logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
let n =
  try:
    var n: int
    let processedChars = paramStr(1).parseInt(n)
    if processedChars == 0:
      quit "Expected number"
    n
  except ValueError:
    quit "Parsed integer is out of the valid range"
```

Also note that [`parseInt`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/parseutils.html#parseInt%2Cstring%2Cint%2Cint) doesn't return the parsed value, but rather the number of parsed characters.